# Read multipart/form-data twice

Tags: asp.net-web-api, multipartform-data, hmac

I have an ASP.NET WebApi, clients are authenticated via HMAC.

Authentication is done in an AuthenticationFilter.
For the comparison of the HMAC key with the one provided by the client I need to read `Request.Content`. Everything is fine until here.

In ParameterBinding I also need to read from Request.Content. This works fine, until content is not `multipart/form-data`. `StringContent` and `ByteArrayContent` can be read multiple times via `content.ReadAsStringAsync()` / `content.ReadAsByteArrayAsync()`, but `ReadAsMultipartAsync()` can only be called once.

So, after authentication I can not read content again (e.g. in ParamterBinding) for extracting data / images etc from the request content.

I read that `ReadAsStringAsync()` / `ReadAsByteArrayAsync()` calls `LoadIntoBufferAsync()` internally, which loads request content into a memory buffer. But doing this with my multipart content does not solve this problem.

Exception is:

> Unexpected end of MIME multipart stream. MIME multipart message is not
>   complete.

Answer (score 2):

You could rewind the input stream after reading it if you have access to `HttpContext.Current` (not self hosted). Like this:

```
HttpContext.Current.Request.InputStream.Position=0;
```

Comment: I've done this and its working. But isn't it a little hack? Documentation says, that you can read it only once. ;-)

Comment: Sure feels like a hack :/ Maybe somebody else can provide a better solution.